# jQuery uncheck checkboxes after remove();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I `uncheck` all `input[name='select-check` after an `.item` is deleted through the function using `remove();`?

I want the `.active` class to remain on the `.delete` button any time an `input[name='select-check` is selected and if an item is deleted, the `checkboxes` need to be `unchecked`.

This process is to demonstrate a completion of the item selection and deletion process. After deletion, no selections should be remaining and therefore the `.delete` button is **no longer** in it's `.active` state.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".select-all").on("click", function() {
    $(this).is(":checked") ?
      $(".select-input")
      .prop("checked", true)
      .change() :
      $(".select-input")
      .prop("checked", false)
      .change();
  });
});
//delete btn color
var btncolor = $("input[name='select-check']:checkbox");
btncolor.on("change", function() {
  $(".delete").toggleClass("active", btncolor.is(":checked"));
});
//delete selected inputs
$(".delete").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".post-list")
    .find(".select-input:checked")
    .closest(".item")
    .remove();
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}

.pick-select {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.select-block {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 3px solid;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
  <div class="selectall-btn">
    <input type="checkbox" id="selectall" class="select-all" name="select-check" />
    <label class="selectall-label" for="selectall"><span></span>Select All
</label>
  </div>
  <button class="delete">delete</button>
</div>
<div class="post-list">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="select-block">
      <label class="pick-select">
<input id="post-select1" type="checkbox" class="select-input" name="select-check">
</label> 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="select-block">
      <label class="pick-select">
<input id="post-select2" type="checkbox" class="select-input" name="select-check">
</label> 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the question is unclear can you properly frame what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to `uncheck` all of the `input` with `name="select-check"` after `.delete` is pressed and the selected items are removed.

Comment: If you remove the `.item` from the DOM, the checkbox will be removed with it. Therefore there is no need to uncheck it.

Comment: That is what I thought, until I tried checking and then unchecking the remaining item. The `.active` class is never removed. I'm not sure why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time an event occurs check the number of `checked` checkboxes. If its length is 0, remove class with :

```
if ($(".select-input:checked").length == 0) {
  $(".delete").removeClass('active');
}
```

Full code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".select-all").on("click", function() {
    $(this).is(":checked") ?
      $(".select-input")
      .prop("checked", true)
      .change() :
      $(".select-input")
      .prop("checked", false)
      .change();
    if ($(".select-input:checked").length == 0) {
      $(".delete").removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
//delete btn color
var btncolor = $("input[name='select-check']:checkbox");
btncolor.on("change", function() {
  $(".delete").toggleClass("active", btncolor.is(":checked"));
  if ($(".select-input:checked").length == 0) {
    $(".delete").removeClass('active');
  }
});
//delete selected inputs
$(".delete").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".post-list")
    .find(".select-input:checked")
    .closest(".item")
    .remove();

  if ($(".select-input:checked").length == 0) {
    $(".delete").removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}

.pick-select {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.select-block {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 3px solid;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
  <div class="selectall-btn">
    <input type="checkbox" id="selectall" class="select-all" name="select-check" />
    <label class="selectall-label" for="selectall"><span></span>Select All
</label>
  </div>
  <button class="delete">delete</button>
</div>
<div class="post-list">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="select-block">
      <label class="pick-select">
<input id="post-select1" type="checkbox" class="select-input" name="select-check">
</label> 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="select-block">
      <label class="pick-select">
<input id="post-select2" type="checkbox" class="select-input" name="select-check">
</label> 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A better way is defining this event handler for document:

```
$(document).on('click change', function() {
  if($(".select-input:checked").length == 0) {
    $(".delete").removeClass('active');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".select-all").on("click", function() {
    $(this).is(":checked") ?
      $(".select-input")
      .prop("checked", true)
      .change() :
      $(".select-input")
      .prop("checked", false)
      .change();
  });
});
//delete btn color
var btncolor = $("input[name='select-check']:checkbox");
btncolor.on("change", function() {
  $(".delete").toggleClass("active", $("input[name='select-check']:checked").length);
}); 
//delete selected inputs
$(".delete").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".post-list")
    .find(".select-input:checked")
    .closest(".item")
    .remove();

    $(".delete").removeClass('active');
});
```

> $(".delete").removeClass('active');

Delete button will delete the active class

Comment: This won't work with `remove();` because the item is still checked somehow. If you add `$(".delete").removeClass('active');` and delete an item and then check and uncheck another, the `.active` class remains on even when the input is unchecked.

Comment: I appreciate

btncolor's event

Comment: This only toggles the class every time one of the checkboxes is checked. I need the `.acitve` class added to the `.delete` button anytime a checkbox is checked and only has it's class removed when no inputs are checked.

Answer (score 1):

I think I simplified your code a bit... While adding behaviors.

Now, the delete button gets its color when one or more `.select-input` are checked... And of course when the `.select-all` is checked.

When at least one `.select-input` is unchecked, the `.select-all` also is.

I think the main trick I added here is to use `.trigger()` to use some already written parts of the desired behavior. Then, using meaningfull variable names helps a lot. It was not always obvious that `btncolor` was the checkbox collection.

Have a look at the comments in code.

Also notice that [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) without an event handler passed as argument does strictly nothing. To **trigger** a change event, you need `.trigger("change")`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".select-all").on("change", function() {
    
    // Look if the select all control is checked.
    var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
    
    // Check the select input and add a color to the delete button -- Or the opposite.
    $(".select-input").prop("checked", isChecked);
    $(".delete").toggleClass("active", isChecked);
  });

  // Add a color to the delete button
  $(".select-input").on("change", function(){
    
    // Look if at least one checkbox is checked.
    var isChecked = $(".select-input").is(":checked");
    
    // Add or remove the color of the delete button
    $(".delete").toggleClass("active", isChecked);
    
    // Look if ALL checkboxes are checked.
    var areAllChecked = true;
    $(".select-input").each(function(){
      if(!$(this).is(":checked")){
        areAllChecked = false;
      }
    });
    
    // Need to have the select all control checked or unchecked?
    $(".select-all").prop("checked", areAllChecked);
  });

  // Delete selected inputs
  $(".delete").on("click",function(event) {
    $(".select-input:checked")
      .closest(".item")
      .remove();
    
    // Uncheck the select all control.
    $(".select-all").prop("checked",false).trigger("change");
  });

});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}

.pick-select {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.select-block {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 3px solid;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
  <div class="selectall-btn">
    <input type="checkbox" id="selectall" class="select-all" name="select-check" />
    <label class="selectall-label" for="selectall"><span></span>Select All
    </label>
  </div>
  <button class="delete">delete</button>
</div>
<div class="post-list">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="select-block">
      <label class="pick-select">
        <input id="post-select1" type="checkbox" class="select-input" name="select-check">
      </label> 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="select-block">
      <label class="pick-select">
        <input id="post-select2" type="checkbox" class="select-input" name="select-check">
      </label> 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```